# File not found error getting when trying to type url

Tags: asp.net

I have uploaded my website on ftp's httpdocs folder when i go to

Default.aspx page it gives me File not found error, I had use publish

website options  and my project contains Default.aspx page as start

page.

All published project files are uploaded and still i am getting File not Found error.
when i try to type files in internet explorers address bar.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site's httpdocs folder in a main domain, i.e. example.com or is it a subdomain like sub.example.com. In the later case you might have to put the files in a different directory.